# C++ double initialization

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class circle
{
public:
    circle();
    circle(double radius);
    double circlerad(void);
    double area(void);
    double circumference(void);

private:
    double rad;

};

circle::circle()
{
    double rad = 0;
}

circle::circle(double radius)
{
    cout << radius << endl;
    double rad = radius;
}

double circle::circlerad(void)
{
    return rad;
}

double circle::area(void)
{
    double res;

    res = rad * rad * 3.14;

    return res;
}

double circle::circumference(void)
{
    return (double) rad * 2 * 3.14;
}

double radius(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    double rad = 0;

    double xm, ym;

    xm = (double)(x1 + x2) / 2;
    ym = (double)(y1 + y2) / 2;

    rad = sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));

    return rad;
}

int main(void)
{
    double rad;
    int x1, y1;
    int x2, y2;

    cout << "x1 : ";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "y1 : ";
    cin >> y1;
    cout << "x2 : ";
    cin >> x2;
    cout << "y2 : ";
    cin >> y2;

    *circle one((double)radius(x1, y1, x2, y2));*

    cout << fixed << one.area() << endl;
    //cout << fixed << one.circumference() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is my code to calculate circle area and circumference.

But the problem is that when I initialize circle one, regardless of radius(x1, y1, x2, y2) value,

it always initialize to -9.2559631349317831e+061.

Comment: You forgot to check whether your input operations succeed, so your program essentially has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `ym` and `xm` are not used, make sure you cast them to doubles BEFORE you work with them.

Comment: The proper way to initialize members with a parameter is a constructor initializer list. Any good book will cover that early on in classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialise circle::rad here (instead you use local variable rad):

```
circle::circle()
{
    double rad = 0;
}

circle::circle(double radius)
{
    cout << radius << endl;
    double rad = radius;
}
```

you should do something like:

```
circle::circle(): rad(0)
{
}

circle::circle(double radius): rad(radius)
{
}
```

Comment: You are expecting the OP to run before they can walk.

Comment: @TonyK, I don't think assigning to the members to "initialize" them should even be taught before the list.

Answer (score 1):

`double rad` declares a local variable, which is not the same as the class member `rad`. The simplest fix:

```
circle::circle()
{
    rad = 0;
}

circle::circle(double radius)
{
    cout << radius << endl;
    rad = radius;
}
```